# Is there any way to close the Tk() window while calling another Tk() window and both Tk() windows are two different python file?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to close the Tk() window while calling another Tk() window like in java we call another frame for 1st frame and close the 1st frame using dispose() method?

For eg. assume two python code first.py and second.py both contents tkinter GUI. In first.py there is a button. I want to do when someone clicks the button it redirects to second.py and the first.py will automatically close...

Like in java we use Frame.dispose() method to close the frame automatically while clicking on a button and it's also able to handle opening of another frame.

Comment: I believe you can just close the window and open another... Do you not know the method to do this? I'm confused.

Comment: For second.py to close the window, it'd need to know the variable/reference to the 1st frame. Do you mean that first.py and second.py are both submodules of the same application, and they can share/exchange variables? Or do you have 2 independent python processes running?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: @Demi-Lune Yes, first.py and second.py both are submodules of the same application.

Comment: @BryanOakley   yes, I tried it. second.py will open when clicking on a button on first.py but I don't find any process to automatically close the first.py while clicking on the button on first.py and calling of second.py..

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible but a bit of a strange request. Most of the time when working with a GUI at least Tkinter in Python you only ever want one instance of `Tk()` and then you use the different container options to manage everything else.

Here is a basic example of what it is you are asking for (not recommended however):

```
import tkinter as tk


class App1(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text='1st TK window!').pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='close app 1 and open app 2', command=self.process_close_and_open).pack()

    def process_close_and_open(self):
        self.destroy()
        start_app2()


class App2(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text='2nd TK window!').pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='close app 2 and open app 1', command=self.process_close_and_open).pack()

    def process_close_and_open(self):
        self.destroy()
        start_app1()


def start_app1():
    App1().mainloop()


def start_app2():
    App2().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_app1()
```

Here is an example that better fits how you should be using Tkinter with only one instance of `TK()` and then switching what is in the working frames.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.working_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.first_frame()

    def first_frame(self):
        self.working_frame.destroy()
        self.working_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.working_frame.pack()
        tk.Label(self.working_frame, text='1st TK frame!').pack()
        tk.Button(self.working_frame, text='close frame 1 and open frame 2', command=self.second_frame).pack()

    def second_frame(self):
        self.working_frame.destroy()
        self.working_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.working_frame.pack()
        tk.Label(self.working_frame, text='2st TK frame!').pack()
        tk.Button(self.working_frame, text='close frame 2 and open frame 1', command=self.first_frame).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

There are several other ways to build a multi-window and/or multi-frame GUI with Tkinter bot none of them I have used or found to be acceptable include the use of 2 separate instances of `Tk()`

In case you are asking about running an application after the application is destroyed you can do that by provided a second set of code after the mainloop thought I have not seen a reason to do this.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text='1st TK frame!').pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='close frame 1 and open frame 2', command=self.destroy).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text='2st TK frame!').pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='close frame 2', command=self.destroy).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```